# show and hide element options for my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm having a little bit of difficulties when I need to hide an element on a page.

I am using this script to create my multiselect dropdown element which is the main controller for the elements on the page (http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#the-basics1).

It returns an array of selected elements and my elements have their showIfValues set in a JSON file.

My functions should do this:

1. I get selected values from the dropdown element in array (ex. ["value1", "value2"]).
2. Going through all the elements and find where in showIfValue is any value from the array above, show it
3. In the change of the multiselect dropdown, if any of the fields are removed, remove the element but leave the rest on the page.

Legend in showHideHendler function:

- *inp* is the id of the input field I would like to show on the page
- *controlInp* is the control input (in this case multiselect dropdown)
- *value* is the array populated with the showIfValues from JSON file of the elements

So far I made it here. These are the things I have implemented.

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.concat(arr2).filter(function (val) {
        if (!(arr1.includes(val) && arr2.includes(val)))
            return val;
    });
}

function getSelectedValues(controlInput){
    if($('#' + controlInput).attr("multiple") === "multiple"){
        // var selectValues = $('#' + controlInput).multipleSelect("getSelects");
        var selectValues = [];
        if($('#' + controlInput).multipleSelect("getSelects") != null) {
            selectValues = $('#' + controlInput).multipleSelect("getSelects");  
        }

        return selectValues;
    }
}

var multipleShowHideHandler = (function() {

    var selectedValues = [];

    function setSelectedValues(value){
        selectedValues.push(value);
    }

    function overrideSelected(value){
        selectedValues = value;
    }

    function getSelectedValues(){
        return selectedValues;
    }

    return {
        setSelectedValues: setSelectedValues,
        getSelectedValues: getSelectedValues,
        overrideSelected: overrideSelected
    }

})();



 function showHideHandler(inp, controlInp, value) {
    if (!$('#' + controlInp).is(':checkbox') && !($.isArray(value))) {
        value = $.makeArray(value);
    }

    var selectedValues = getSelectedValues(controlInp);

    if(($('#' + controlInp).attr("multiple") === "multiple") && !$.isEmptyObject(selectedValues)){
        $('#' + controlInp).change(function(){

            var oldState = multipleShowHideHandler.getSelectedValues();
            var selectedValues = getSelectedValues(controlInp);

            if($.isEmptyObject(oldState)){
                $.each(selectedValues, function(i, val){
                    multipleShowHideHandler.setSelectedValues(val);
                });
            }

            var differentArray = diffArray(selectedValues, oldState);

            if(!$.isEmptyObject(differentArray)){
                if(($.inArray(differentArray[0], value) !== -1)){
                    $('#' + inp + 'Container').hide();
                }
                multipleShowHideHandler.overrideSelected(selectedValues);
            }

            //check diff
            /*if(!$.isEmptyObject(selectedValues) && !$.isEmptyObject(oldState)){
                var diff = diffArray(selectedValues, oldState);
            }*/

            $.each(selectedValues, function(i, val){
                if(($.inArray(val, value) !== -1)){
                    $('#' + inp + 'Container').show();
                }
            });
        });


    }else if (($.inArray($('#' + controlInp).val(), value) > -1) || $('#' + controlInp).prop('checked') === value) {
        $('#' + inp + 'Container').show();
    } else {
        $('#' + inp + 'Container').hide();
    }
}
```

This works on some elements, but the moment it overrides my oldState the fields are not hidden.

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking and trying many things, I have found that the easiest way is basically to remove all elements and show them again on any change of the multiple select dropdown element.

So the final code looks like this:

```
if(($('#' + controlInp).attr("multiple") === "multiple") && !$.isEmptyObject(selectedValues)){
        $('#' + controlInp).change(function(){
            var selectedValues = getSelectedValues(controlInp);
            if(!$.isEmptyObject(selectedValues)){
                $('#' + inp + 'Container').hide();
                $.each(selectedValues, function(i, val){
                    if(($.inArray(val, value) !== -1)){
                        $('#' + inp + 'Container').show();
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#' + inp + 'Container').hide();
            }
        });
}
```

There is no need to add a before state and after so this is the only thing I need.

DiffArray and multipleShowHideHandler are no longer needed.

Hope this helps someone in the future.